# Conversion of a star

Tags: astrophysics, stars, neutron-stars, stellar-evolution

I need to know what would happen to a star that has size 2 times the solar mass. I guess it would either be a neutron or red giant. Is that right?

Comment: Hi user. Welcome to Physics.SE. In order for a question to be properly answered, you need to define it properly. For now, your question is somewhat vague. You can have a look at Wiki articles about [neutron star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star) and [red giant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_giant) ;-)

Comment: But i am confused about the answer

Comment: Your question title asks the difference between both, while your body asks the choice, whether a $2M_{sun}$ star would become a neutron star or not. Can you please phrase what do you actually require? Because, such stars have the red giant phase. Neutron stars are only for stars blowing up as supernovae...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat poorly worded. You say, *"... the star has size 2 times the mass of sun"*. I can't understand this phrase for sure. Still, they are completely different phases of very different stars.

Wiki links on [Neutron Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star) and [Red Giant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_giant) are much good for this question on [Stellar evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_evolution).

Once the main sequence stage is complete, a star whose mass is comparable to our sun (0.5 to 8 times $M_{sun}$), then the star becomes a red giant and finally ends up as a dwarf (just like our sun). Massive stars (having much higher mass $>8M_{sun}$) become red super-giant and finally explode as a supernova whose remnants maybe a black-hole or a neutron star (which is also based on their mass).

Comment: ends up as a *white* dwarf... after losing about 1.4 solar masses on the AGB phase.